# Applying python functions with parameters to apache beam pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, data-processing, apache-beam

I am using apache beam to carry out data preprocessing with python on a data sample shown below

```
userid   itemid  rating timestamp
1          2       3.2    10:59
1          3       3.5    11:59
2          3       4.2    10:10
2          4       1.5    10:59
```

My code is shown below

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

beam.__version__



# delete timestamp column
def del_col(data, col_name: str):
    del data[col_name]
    return data
  
# check for null values
def check_null(data, col_name1:str, col_name2:str, col_name3:str):
    return len(data[col_name1]) > 0 and len(data[col_name2]) > 0 and len(data[col_name3]) > 0

# converting to comma deliminated format
def format_data(data):
  data = ','.join([data['userid'], data['itemid'], data['ratings']])
  return data

def print_row(data):
  print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  options = PipelineOptions()
  input_file = 'data.csv' 
  with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    (pipeline | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file, skip_header_lines=0) # read data with beam
        | 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
        | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"userid": x[0], "itemid": x[1], "ratings": x[2], "timestamp": x[3]}) # format to dict and name columns
        | 'DeleteNullData' >> beam.Filter(check_null('userid', 'itemid', 'ratings')) # pick non null columns
        | 'DeleteUnwantedData' >> beam.Map(del_col(col_name='timestamp')) # delete irrelevant columns
        | 'FormatData' >> beam.Map(format_data)
```

The issue here is that I need to make these functions modular and I don't know how to approach developing these functions.

```
def check_null(data, col_name1:str, col_name2:str, col_name3:str):
    return len(data[col_name1]) > 0 and len(data[col_name2]) > 0 and len(data[col_name3]) > 0

# converting to comma deliminated format
def format_data(data):
  data = ','.join([data['userid'], data['itemid'], data['ratings']])
  return data
```

Also, how do I pass the functions to the apache beam pipeline with the parameters, I tried this but it wasn't working as there is no way I can get the data parameter

```
| 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
        | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"userid": x[0], "itemid": x[1], "ratings": x[2], "timestamp": x[3]}) # format to dict and name columns
        | 'DeleteNullData' >> beam.Filter(check_null('userid', 'itemid', 'ratings')) # pick non null columns
        | 'DeleteUnwantedData' >> beam.Map(del_col(col_name='timestamp')) # delete irrelevant columns
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want and how you want to make the fn modular, could you clarify?

Comment: So I already noticed that my function was modular a bit, but I was wondering if I can make reusable for other scenarios where I had more than 3 columns.